# GWT Widget inheritance and Compositions

Tags: gwt, composition, uibinder

In my GWT project, I have a widget "composition(? *not 100% sure about the term*)", called `MenuItem`. This has the following structure:

```
<div class="some invariable class">
    <div class="first-child"><!-- something --></div>
    <div class="middle-element"><label /></div>
</div>
```

I want to create widgets, which all have this structure, but in place of `<!-- something -->`, for instance an `IconMenuItem` would put a FontAwesome icon, or `ImageMenuItem` would put a small thumbnail there.

I'm kind of new to GWT and reading the documentation and some topics here at SO, I suspect that `MenuItem` should extend `Composite` and `*MenuItem` should extend this `MenuItem`.

However, I'm not sure how I would enforce the HTML structure above without duplicating it. I'm also unsure about what the best practice would be to allow different types of elements, like I said about the image and icon example.

What would be the good class structure, which class should inherit/compose which class?